# ASP session expiration before timeout setting

Tags: session, asp-classic

Some of my legacy program is using `ASP` (not ASP.Net), and even if I set long session expire time, for example to 20 minutes, sometimes in short time (e.g. in several minutes) I will still notice session expire error box –

> "too much idle time, please login again."

Any ideas to analyze further? Not sure whether it is my code bug or server (browser) configuration issue, since not all client/server combinations are met with this strange issue.

The session expire box is triggered by my code:

```
<%
    if session("timeToken") = "" then
%>

<script language = "JavaScript">
<!--
window.alert ("too much idle time, please login again");
//-->
</script>
<%
response.End()
end if
%>
```

Comment: Where is the code you've provided?  If it's javascript/vbscript on the client side, you shouldn't be able to get session variables, and if it's server side, you shouldn't be able to do an alert...

Comment: @Damovisa, I have posted my code. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Gotcha - I refreshed and you'd updated the code :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas based on your update:

1. Is there another reason your `session("timeToken")` could be empty?  Another piece of code somewhere or perhaps the variable was misspelled somewhere?
2. How does the actual value of `session("timeToken")` change in your code?  Is it set when the session starts?  Is it updated periodically?  What value does it store?

The code you've written seems to be fine, so if it's not a code issue it will likely be a genuine session problem... just some things to check first.

**Updates:**

- ASP session state is generally maintained using cookies - could you check that the client has cookies enabled?
- Is the ASP application served by more than one server?  If it's being served from a web farm or cluster, you'll need to make sure that session state can persist across the machines or that a user's session is "sticky" - that is, it's always served by the same server.

More information and help can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx

Comment: What do you mean "2.How does the actual value of session("timeToken") change?" -- in what situations will it change automatically out of my code?

Comment: Appreciate if you could let me know any settings from IIS or OS  or browser side which impact session expiration?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've put some more ideas in my answer

Comment: @Damovisa, a further question. Is it elegant code to check whether session variable is String.Empty to decide whether session expires as I showed in my original code? I have this confusion because I did not find formal documents which mention this is elegant way.

Comment: My client enables session and I am using single web server to host the web application, using in-process session management.

Comment: @George2 - I don't know if I'd call it elegant - it should work though.  Have a look at the second question in my answer as well - I haven't got a clear idea of how you're using this session variable.  It could be something as simple as it being explicitly set to "" at some point...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you site stays in the same case sensitive folders

e.g.

http://myserver.com/MyWebSite/

does not have the same session cookie as

http://myserver.com/mywebsite/

So it would log you out.

Comment: First I've heard of that behaviour?  Can you supply any references for this?

Comment: "Many Web browsers, including Microsoft Internet Explorer version 4.0, or later, and Netscape browsers, preserve the case of the cookie path." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525506.aspx

Comment: and lots and lots of bitter experience when IE 4 came out and my ASP application was ruined ;)

Comment: @u07ch, we are using IE 7 or IE 8. Seems this issue is not for IE 7 or IE 8?

Answer (score 1):

It could be the IIS limitation on your application seesion timeout.

Try this:

1. Right click on you app folder in IIS
2. Then go Properties -> Virtual Directory Tab -> Then the Configuration Button on the right bottom
3. If it's disabled, then create the application first clicking the button Create
4. Under the configuration window click on the Options tab and you will find SESSION TIMEOUT set by default to 20(mins)

hope this is the aswer to your prayers :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that the application pool your app runs in is not recycling for some reason.  For example does it have a more aggressive idle timeout (in a test scenario you may be the only on using the app and hence your not using it constitutes not just an idle session but an idle application).

The all sorts of different reasons that tha app pool can be configured for that will trigger a recycle.

Check the event logs when you have an unexcepted timeout, does anything look unusual there?

Comment: I am interested in your reply, a few questions/comments, 1. why application pool recycling will make session timeout (I think IIS should be well designed that is there is live session, should not make application pool recycling) and how to check current timeout setting in IIS? 2. From Windows event log or from IIS log, is it able to check whether session timeout issue is caused by application pool recycle? 3. "Check the event logs when you have an unexcepted timeout" -- event log of IIS? of OS or of my application?

Comment: @George: 1.  It is not bad design for IIS to timeout in this way.  It is good design that the app pool understands little about the sorts of applications running in it.  Hence its quite appropriate that it is ignorant of application specific features such as session management.  In IIS 6 manager open app pools branch, select properties on a pool, on performance tab there is a Idle timeout section.  In IIS 7 click Advanced Settings... in the actions pane once you have select the app pool, the idle timeout is in the Process Model category.

Comment: @George: 2 and 3. Not specifically but unexpected recycles are logged.  In IIS7 Advanced Settings for an app pool also has a Generate Recycle Event Log Entry value where you can configure what recycle events generate logs.  I wouldn't be surprised if IIS 6 had such a feature but its not exposed in the management UI that I can see.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, 1. if I set session timeout in my code explicitly, and also configured session timeout in IIS concole, and also configured application pool idle time, which one will take effect? 2. I think the application pool restart or idle for some time, sessions will all be expired, correct? If yes, I am interested how will application pool treat idle? The same as how ASP treats idle (in the context of session expire)?