# How to solve session issue on Content Delivery (CD) server using Sitecore 6.6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, sitecore

In a project (build with Sitecore version 6.6 and ASP.net Webforms) I experience a strange session loss issue on Content Delivery (CD) server. I googled on this subject using the keywords ASP.net and session loss. I found a lot of interesting stuff, but not the solution.

In the meanwhile, I figured out that it is nearly impossible that the cause of the issue is an Application Pool recycle or the auto-bot detect function inside Sitecore.

The way we write data to the session.

```cs
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = "data here";
```

The way we read data from a session.

```cs
string data = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["name"];
```

SessionState configuration

```xml
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

The Sitecore configuration is the default. The session loss is at random times within 5 minutes. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Do you have more than one CD server?

Comment: How are you certain that application pool recycling is not causing this. There are many reasons/cases in which the app pool recycles itself

Comment: No, one CD-server. I added the sessionstate configuration to the main post.

Comment: have you tried this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/951079/2183396
also you can try setting cookieless="UseCookies"

Comment: have you looked into sitecore logs when this issue happens?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29283291/81631 - for webforms you need to include the <sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" /> control to your layout.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is following setting.

```
 <authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="180" />
</authentication>
```

Also look at session setting in IIS, probably there is something incorrectly setup.

I would suggest that you try setting up a session state server and see if the problem still persists. 
Additionally, it is worth to ask, are you using one or multiple CD servers.